How can I get a MUI grid to adjust row height for dynamic content?
I am new to React MUI DataGrid, trying to create a table look like the following.
How do i create a column with Tags as its values, the height of the row should be dynamically adjusted based on the number of items in Tag column.

I did the following to create a tag column in data grid. But the row height is static and the elements get cut if the number of tags is high.
columns = [{
      field: "tags",
      headerName: "Tags",
      renderCell: (params) => (
        <Stack direction="row" spacing={0.25}>
          <Fragment>            
            {params.row.tags.map((tag) => (
              <Chip label={tag} />
            ))}
          </Fragment>
        </Stack>
      ),
      editable: true,
      flex: 2.5,
    }]


This has nothing to do with tags. It's a matter of allowing the grid to contain whatever content you place in it. I suggest revising your title and question post. Please take the [tour].

Did you read the docs?

@isherwood Yes i did read the docs, The auto row height adjustment does not work if i use renderCell option as listed above in the sample code.

I see. You may need to update the rows after render. Here's a similar question: Material-UI DataGrid dynamic row height based on text content

@isherwood Thanks, getRowHeight={() => 'auto'} worked. But i had to remove the  from the above code. That was causing it not get wrapped.

After some help from the comments, i was able to get the answer. Had to remove the <Stack> in the renderCell option and add getRowHeight={() => "auto"} to <DataGrid />. <Stack> was preventing the cell values from getting wrapped.
